# Button not appearing circular in css

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to create a group of circular buttons with CSS:

```
.button {
display:inline;
height:10px;
width:10px;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius:50%;
}
```

However, my buttons appear to be more ovoid in-shape, as shown in the screenshot below. Why is this and how can I address this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because by default the `<button>` element has `padding`. Set `padding: 0;`

```css
.button {
  display:inline;
  height:10px;
  width:10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius:50%;

  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="button"></button>
```

In google chrome the default padding for a button is `padding: 2px 6px 3px;` which means

```
padding-top: 2px;
padding-right: 6px;
padding-bottom: 3px;
padding-left: 6px;
```

and this is what makes it look ovoid. So **`padding` does not have to be zero but you must set all values to the same size**:

```css
.button {
  display:inline;
  height:10px;
  width:10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius:50%;

  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button"></button>
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks! I'm curious: what's the default padding for a button? Why does that cause them to be ovoid?

Comment: @Eragon20 The default sizes from padding on the button might vary across browsers. If you use the web-inspector tools you find the padding, (in chrome `padding: 2px 6px 3px;`). This is because "normally" you will have some text inside the button and like that it's kind a centered nicely...

Comment: @Eragon20 so you could also do `padding: 20px;` and then it's also not ovoid. Important is just that all four `padding-top`, `padding-right`, `padding-bottom`, `padding-left` have the same value to make it circular which is not the case by default with `padding: 2px 6px 3px;`